# How to get along with XML structure in eclipse or Qt Java project? (!warning! noob content inside)

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, qt

give me some links, that will give me a clue what XML documents are responsible for in my project. All programing books I found are about syntax and OOP stuff, but i have no idea what to do in software development environment.

Thanks!

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking for.  Are you just wondering how to set up Eclipse with some simple XMLs and read them?  Or are you looking for something specifically for QT?

Comment: I just wanna say, I create eclipse project and have no idea, where to write my code, add elements and so on... 
Situation is this bad (

Comment: It´s still not clear for me. You want to do a java project which contains xml libraries?

Comment: Are you talking about a web project and the context.xml and web.xml files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a new Java project in Eclipse:

1. Open Perspective (button on the far right) -> Java
2. File -> New -> Java Project
3. Give it any name you want and say finish
4. Right-click this new project, New -> Package
5. Enter com.foo (or whatever you want, all lower case, com.something) and say finish
6. Right-click this new package, New -> Class
7. Enter XmlReader (or whatever), select check-box by `public static void main` and say finish
8. Right-click the project, New -> Other -> XML -> XML File
9. Enter whatever name you want and say finish

Now you have an XML and a Java class to read it with.  Put whatever you want in that XML and then write some Java code in that XmlReader to read it.

Edit: Make sure you have "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" from http://eclipse.org/downloads/ so that you have the XML tools.